# No puedo ejecutar Scripts con Python 2.7 ni 3.7

Tags: python

Desde que me instalé Python tengo el problema que al momento de utilizar en la consola del sistema (mi caso es windows) python stipt1.py no ejecuta el script, es decir, al presionar enter debería correr el script y mostrar las distintas instrucciones, pero por el contrario se abre la consola de python o gpython o el archivo python.exe en el directorio de instalación y ya intenté correrlo desde sublime text 3, brackets y atom y ocurre lo mismo.

A la derecha ejecuto el archivo .py y a la izquiera se abre la consola y no muestra nada más.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sin conocer mas detalles, apostaría a que es un problema de rutas prueba correr con la ruta completa por ejemplo: (Cambia los valores a tu ruta especifica en windows)

```
C:\python27\python.exe Z:\code\hw01\script.py
```

Tomado de este [enlace](http://www.cs.bu.edu/courses/cs108/guides/runpython.html), sin embargo ya que estás empezando con python te recomendaría instalar alguna distribución en Linux, intentalo que no muerde.